# Image not switching on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get this image to scroll through images on hover but its not work. Live demo at: http://codepen.io/bskousen/pen/Ksphr

Using jquery

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imageBox').hover(startScroll, stopScroll);
});

var scrollInterval;
var i = 2;

function startScroll() {
    scrollInterval = setInterval(scrollImages(this), 100);
}

function stopScroll() {
    i = 2;
    $(this).children('img').fadeOut();
    $(this).children('img:nth-child(1)').fadeIn();
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
}

function scrollImages(x) {
    $('#count').append('running' + i + ' ');
    var imageCount = $(x).children('img').length;
    $(x).children('img').fadeOut();
    $(x).children('img:nth-child(' + i + ')').fadeIn();
    if (i == imageCount) {
        i = 2;
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong? What do you mean by "not work"?

Comment: When I hover the image changes from 1 to 2. Is there something else that is supposed to happen?

Comment: When I hover over the image I want it to scroll to image 1, 2, 3, etc but it only goes to 2 and stops.

Comment: Do you want it to stay at 2, then when you hover again go to 3?  Or go back to 1 on mouse out?

Comment: @dcclassics He wants to when you hover it goes from 1,2,3,... every 10th of a second. Like a counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setInterval is not formatted correctly. Try this:

```
function startScroll() {
    me = this;
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
       scrollImages(me);
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TfnQf/  Note I changed the timeout to 1000. 100 is a bit ridiculous.